# Event Streams integration with Azure?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We are attempting to use a sink from Event Streams to store events in our Azure blob storage. I can see where we can configure a webhook for this purpose, and we are receiving test events to one of our unsecure webhooks. However for prod, we require secure transport, and our Azure instance requires the Ocp-Apim subscription key to be sent in the header. There doesn't appear to be any way to configure this in Event Streams. Has anyone been able to get this or something similar working?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. We were able to set up the event Sink URI with the subscription key using URL encoding. ?subscriptionkey=x.....yyy . This is not in the documentation, but it does work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).